# Multimedia player with fast response?

Tags: media-player, vlc

I need instant scroll, instant track switch.

`VLC` can delay for few seconds and more after each operation, before operating normal.

**UPDATE**

Instant track switch and instant rewind could be useful in foreign language learning. One could switch and rewind to listen the same phrase in different languages while watching movie.

Current delay for many seconds is absolutely unjustified.

Comment: "instant" does not exist in computer time. Every operation takes time to process, and that time also depends on your hardware (CPU, RAM, ...) and on the track itself, not just the player

Comment: Instant means too fast to notice and of course means no any unjustified delay. Waiting for more than 5 seconds on sound track switch can't be explained by any modern CPU, RAM or hardware.